# Is it possible to send ASCII control codes via RS232?

Tags: serial-port

I would like to receive and send bytes that have special meaning in ASCII code like End of Text, End of Transmission etc. but I am not sure if it is allowed. Can it break my communication? Sending and receiving looks like reading from file that is why I doubt I can directly use this specific values. I use Windows OS.

EDIT: I have tested it and there is no problem with any sign. All of control ASCII characters can be sent via RS 232. Both reading and writing cause no unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You need to improve your question.  Do you expect these ASCII control codes to perform any special actions?  Or you you simply need to send binary values that just happen to have the same values as these ASCII control codes?  The programing language that you expect to use may also have relevance.

Comment: Also please say which API function or library so we can give a detailed specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

RS232 is a very binary protocol. It does not even assume 8-bit bytes, let alone ASCII. The fact that on Windows, you use file functions does not matter either. Those too do not assume text data, although those do assume 8-bit byets.

Answer (score -1):

RS-232 nodes do not interpret the data except in software flow control mode (XOn/XOff). You use this mode only if both parties agree and agree on the values of XOn and XOff.

The values are historically based on the ASCII DC1 and DC3 characters but the only thing that matters is their values, 0x11, and 0x13.

If you haven't set up software flow control, all values are passed through as-is.

Comment: *"all values are passed through as-is."* -- Not my downvote, but a ***line discipline*** can remove/replace/insert control characters.  Don't know if Windows has line discipline capabilities like POSIX.  If your answer only applies to the hardware level, then you're ignoring the OP's stipulation of using Windows.

Comment: @sawdust Well, yes, there are other configurations and libraries that implement such features. The basic question is: Can you transfer binary data unmolested in Windows? And, the answer is: Yes you can.

Comment: I think I understand why your answer was downvoted (by someone else).  You are asserting that binary transfer mode (aka non-canonical transfer) is specified by disabling software flow control.  Not true for POSIX, and I have no idea about Windows.  I think that the basic question is "can these ASCII control codes be sent in canonical mode"?

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for helping to improve my answer. I'll wait for the question asker to give more detail.